# Updating a row in a Postgres table using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to update a row in a given table using the following Sequelize query:

```
const handleEditProfile = async (req, res) => {
  let medicalconditions = req.body.medicalconditions;
  let allergies = req.body.allergies;
  let bloodtype = req.body.bloodtype;
  let weight = req.body.weight;
  let height = req.body.height;
  let userId = req.body.userid;

  Profile.bulkCreate(
    [{userId: userId, medicalconditions: medicalconditions, allergies: allergies, bloodtype: bloodtype, weight: weight, height: height}],
    {updateOnDuplicate: ['medicalconditions', 'allergies', 'bloodtype', 'weight', 'height']}
  )
  .then(data => {
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  })
};
```

This is what I get in the Postgres DB:

```
 id |      medicalconditions      |     allergies      | bloodtype | weight  |   height   |         createdAt          |         updatedAt          | userId 
----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------
 74 | type 2 diabetes             |   penicillin       |     AB    | 114 lbs |            | 2023-02-13 14:56:21.789-06 | 2023-02-13 14:56:21.789-06 |     40
 90 | hyperthyroidism             | none               | AB        | 120 lbs | 5'4"       | 2023-02-17 18:08:44.503-06 | 2023-02-17 18:08:44.503-06 |     40
```

As you can see, I looked up the "row" by the userId. I want to update the columns mentioned in "updateOnDuplicate" where userId = 40. However, instead of updating the row with the id = 74 and userId = 40, it creates a new row with the id = 90 and userId = 40. How can I fix this without mentioning the primary id?

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  uid: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  },
  DOB: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  }
});

const Profile = sequelize.define('profile', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  medicalconditions: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT
  },
  allergies: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT
  },
  bloodtype: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT
  },
  weight: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT
  },
  height: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT
  }
});

User.hasOne(Profile);
Profile.belongsTo(User);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Profile` records to be unique not only by PK but by `userId` as well you need an unique index/constraint in `Profile` table on `userId`. That way if you don't indicate PK in objects that about to be inserted PostgreSQL will look at fields values that correspond to any unique constraint to decide whether a record with such values already exists or doesn't.
Another benefit of having the unique index on `userid` that you can't create two records with the same `userId` even if you use an individual `create` calls.

Comment: So does that basically mean I need to make “userid” as a unique key? Isn’t primary key (“id” in this case) a unique key already? Can you have more than one unique key?

Comment: Yes, you can have more than one unique key and only one PK. So if you insert records without indicating PK values then PostgreSQL will rely on unique constraints in order to decide whether to update record or try to insert a new one

Comment: It turns out the userId in the "Profile" table is a foreign key. userId is the primary key of "Users" table. What can I do in this case?

Comment: If records in `Profile` should have a unique `userId` values then you just need to add a unique index on `userId` in `Profile`